# Android Studio, I changed the folder name, project won't load

Tags: android, android-studio

I foolishly changed the name of the root folder for my android studio project, using my Win10 PC's File Explorer, and now I can't seem to figure out how to re-open the project in Android Studio 2.2.2 .

I changed that folder name back to the original name, still can't figure out how to open it.

All 2000+ files seem to be intact, and back where they were before my misadventures, but not sure how to get the IDE to allow me to work on this project?

I am returning the programming, after more than a year off...and am pretty much a novice Android programmer.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please add more detail from the build.

Comment: make a new project with same package name and re set up. your project.

Answer (score 0):

start deleting the .idea folder in the root of your project. Then, open your Android Studio select "Open an existing Android Studio project" (or File > Open...) and select your project's folder.